# How did Pettigrew survive Hogwarts as a rat?

Tags: harry-potter, peter-pettigrew

Maybe it was the plot armor, maybe Pettigrew was more intelligent than he looked in the books, but with Pettigrew's abilities, how did he survive Hogwarts?

We know that he was Percy's pet before he was Ron's pet, so he stayed many years in Hogwarts as a pet. Considering how popular cats are around wizards and witches, as well as owls (I don't think toads would be very popular), that makes for a great quantity of animals that could see Pettigrew and think of it as lunch/breakfast/dinner/etc.

Was it mainly the plot armor that made Pettigrew survive as a rat in Hogwarts?

Comment: He only went into hiding as a rat later, after he graduated Hogwarts, when betrayed his friends to Voldemort near the end of the First Wizarding War.  Also even as a rat, he was a cunning and powerful wizard and wasn't one to be eaten by some random cat.

Comment: Pet rats have a typical lifespan of 2-3 years. If he spent all those years concealed in rat form didn't anyone wonder about that?

Comment: So your question really is: How can a human outsmart cats and owls?
One does not need plot armor to do this, even if in form of a rat...

Comment: @triclon I think OP is referring to the time he spent in Hogwarts while pretending to be Percy and Ron's pet, rather than his time there as a student.

Comment: This is rarely the correct answer to a question but…perhaps it involved some sort of magic. Maybe he consumed a potion that made him smell really bad to cats, owls, hypogriffs, and other predators?

Comment: How does anyone survive Hogwarts? That whole place is a creepy death trap of man eating spiders and atrocious faculty vetting policies. Why do they even have a part of the library called the  forbidden section? Because they’re daring you to try something stupid and get yourself killed.

Comment: @AffableAmbler Restricted, not forbidden.

Comment: Excellent points, @AffableAmbler, however, if common sense were applied, the story wouldn't have been nearly as much fun!

Answer (score 7):

In the third book, once Crookshanks the cat is introduced, Pettigrew’s survival indeed becomes a challenge. In the first two books, however, Crookshanks is not around. The only other cat mentioned at Hogwarts during this time is Mrs. Norris, who mainly patrols the corridors. Aside from before school starts, we don’t ever see Scabbers outside the Gryffindor dormitory, so presumably Mrs. Norris was not a threat.

While there are many owls  in Hogwarts as well, they are generally confined to the owlery when not delivering/sending mail, so again this would not be much of a threat to a rat in the dormitory. On the rare occasion that an owl might make a delivery directly to the dormitory, it would presumably be easy enough to take precautions for a few moments.

Comment: Are the owls _confined_ to the owlery or do they just prefer to hang out with their own kind there and eating out instead of prowling the halls looking for indoor dining?

Comment: Seems they prefer to hang out there with their own kind, plus that's where their owners expect to find them, and plot makes them intelligent enough to want to be found. Myself, I think an owl would prefer not to try hunting in the confines of a castle hallway... but if one did, I can't help thinking Mrs. Norris would have been turned into owl food long ago.

Comment: @tsc_chazz Mrs. Norris did visit the owlery once, and it seems that she equally wanted to eat them:   *Mrs. Norris came trotting at his heels, gazing up at the owls overhead and mewing hungrily. There was a restless shifting of wings from above, and a large brown owl snapped his beak in a menacing fashion.* …. *Mrs. Norris cast a last longing look at the owls and followed him.*